Build failed because of webpack errors Error: Process completed with exit code 1
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
⨯ ./src/app/page.jsx:3:1
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/contexts/NameContext'
1 | "use client"
2 |

3 | import { useNameContext } from "@/contexts/NameContext";
| ^
4 | import { useRef, useState } from "react";
5 |
6 |

This was working till i pushed the code to github after that when i run the code it started throwing this error
I tried to change configs in the jsconfig file

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
